# How to use map function instead of for loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, nodes

This is my array :

```
var filteredData = [{ id: 1, phoneno: '91888888888', sender: 'test' },{ id: 2, phoneno: '9199999999999', sender: 'hel' }]
```

I use for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < filteredData.length; i++) {
   if (filteredData[i].sender === test) {
       console.log('worked');
   }else{
       console.log('not worked');
   }
}
```

How to exactly do this with map ? in javascript instead of for loop.

Comment: First, ask yourself this. Is map the right method? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map - doesn't seem to fit

Comment: can you tell me i dont know is it possible to do this use map?

Comment: Share more information about what you are trying to do. Looking at the things now, map doesn't seem to be good fit for your requirement.

Comment: yes, it is possible, but why would you use map instead of forEach? It's like asking if it's possible to use a cucumber in a banana split

Comment: @Jaromanda i want to use map, if you know how to do using map, please post an answer

Comment: `map` is usually used in place where you want to transform the data. In this case you are just printing the data, so there is no need for map. What you probably want is `forEach`

Comment: I wouldn't use map for what you want to do, so I'm not going to post an answer that uses a hammer to screw in a nail

Comment: what you need is not a map but forEach, since you aren't returning anything

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in the comments, `forEach` is better to be used in your example. But if you insist in using `map`, just replace `forEach` with `map` and the code would still work.

```
var filteredData = [{ id: 1, phoneno: '918888888888', sender: 'test' },{ id: 2, phoneno: '918888888888', sender: 'hel' }];

filteredData.forEach(function(item){
   if (item.sender === test) {
       console.log('worked');
   }
   else {
       console.log('not worked');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filteredData.map(value => {
    if (value.sender === test) {
        console.log("worked");
    } else {
        console.log('not worked');
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

By using underscore.js,

```
var filteredData = [{ id: 1, phoneno: '917418306474', sender: 'test' },{ id: 2, phoneno: '917338966917', sender: 'hel' }];

 _.map(filteredData, function(data){
   if (data.sender === test) {
    console.log('worked');
   }else {
    console.log('not worked');}
});
```

Answer (score -3):

```
var filteredData = [{ id: 1, phoneno: '77777777777', sender: 'test' },{ id: 2, phoneno: '917338966917', sender: 'hel' }]
filteredData.map(filterDetails); 
function filterDetails(data) {  
    if(data.sender == 'test'){
     console.log('worked');
     }
     else{
     console.log('not worked');
     }
}
```